# encrypted password in mysql tables, VBA as a front-end

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes

I am trying to add some security at MS ACCESS 2013 applications (using a Mysql BE in the backend).

The first application form will ask for user and password, compare it against a mysql custom table ("USUARIOS", for instance) and grant access if they match or don't elsewhere

But I would like passwords to be stored "encrypted", using AES_ENCRYPT or other convenient algorithm

I have input the user/password directly from mysql-workbench

```
INSERT INTO USUARIOS COLUMN (ALIAS, PWD) 
VALUES ('luis', AES_ENCRYPT('miguel','yucg39dy(9&%$^?bcGSFD'))
```

but I am failing to retrieve the password to compare (from code, using VBA, loading ADO recordsets).

```
rs.open "SELECT AES_DECRYPT(PWD, 'yucg39dy(9&%$^?bcGSFD' FROM USUARIOS WHERE ..'
```

this rs doesn't return the word 'miguel' as intended

I would appreciate any hint on that. Maybe I can use password() or MD5() functions, don't need any key

Comment: Can you pls share the full sql queries used? What is pwd field's data type?

Answer (score 1):

> I have input the user/password directly from mysql-workbench
>
> INSERT INTO USUARIOS COLUMN (ALIAS, PWD)  VALUES ('luis',
>   AES_ENCRYPT('miguel','yucg39dy(9&%$^?bcGSFD'))
>
> rs.open "SELECT AES_DECRYPT(PWD, 'yucg39dy(9&%$^?bcGSFD' FROM USUARIOS WHERE ..'

It's long time ago but maybe try this:

`SELECT AES_DECRYPT(PWD, 'yucg39dy(9&%$^?bcGSFD') AS PWD FROM USUARIOS  WHERE ..' ('User' = 'miguel';)`

All the best

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to retrieve the password.

You should be doing

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USUARIOS WHERE USER = ? AND PWD = AES_ENCRYPT(...)
```

and seeing whether the count was 1 or 0.

It will then become clear to you that you don't need to decrypt the passwords at all, so you can stop that insecure plan and hash them instead.